# MongoDB: Get documents depending on a search term for array field and string field

Tags: mongodb

I need to perform a search on my mongoDB collection based on two fields: `title`, which is a string, and `tags`, which is an array.

Assume this is a sample data for the collection:

```
{
  title: 'A tornado article',
  tags: [
    'nature',
    'storm'
  ]
},
{
  title: 'Just another article',
  tags: [
    'hurricane',
    'type I'
  ]
},
{
  title: 'Different article',
  tags: [
    'tornado',
    'type II'
  ]
}
```

and my search string is `const term = 'tornado type I'`, then I should get all documents as

- the first one has *tornado* in the title
- the second one has an tag *type I*
- the third one has an tag *tornado*

I tried to start with this to perform the search:

```
Collection.find(
  {
    $or: [
      { 'meta.title': new RegExp(term, 'i') },
      { 'meta.tags': term }
    ]
  }
)
```

So with this I would get the first document if the search term would be just `tornado`. With my sample term string I don't get any result.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to return an object that contains any of the tags you need to the the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator, it selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

However to do so you need to pass it an array of your terms, to do so I've splitted your terms on

`" "`  and passed that variable along to the `$in` like so

```
var term = 'tornado type I nature';
var splitted = term.split(' ');

    Collection.find({
        $or: [{
                'title': new RegExp(term, 'i')
            }, {
                "tags": {
                    $in: splitted
                }
            }
        ]
    })
```

Or if you also use to wish the [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html#regex) to search through the tags you could join the array with `|` to build a regex statement after which you can pass it along like this.

```
var term = 'tornado type I nature';
var splitted = term.split(' ');
var splittedRegex = new RegExp(splitted.join('|'), 'i');

Colleciton.find({
    $or: [{
            'title': new RegExp(term, 'i')
        }, {
            "tags": {
                $in: [splittedRegex]
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: This won't work for tags like `type I`, as it would be splitted into two parts. Then a match for `I` would be very often...